# create link button in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` in which Files are displayed with an `Delete` button.

If I click on `delete` the selected Row values change to "no" **Are you sure ?** "yes".
no/yes are created as LinkButtons when delete is clicked.

Now i want them to function like a `gridview` rowcommand but i can't get them to work.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvFiles" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="true"      CssClass="mGrid"  AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"   GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" EnableViewState="true" OnRowCommand="gvFiles_RowCommand" OnPageIndexChanging="gvFiles_PageIndexChanging" >
    <Columns>                
       <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" Text="delete" CommandName="remove"  />   
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>


protected void gvFiles_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)        
{

            SQLConnection SQLCon = new SQLConnection();
            string sCid = Request.QueryString["CatID"].ToString();
            string sdev = Request.QueryString["devID"].ToString();
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            DataTable dtFiles = (DataTable)Session["ActualDevFiles"];
            DataRow dr = dtFiles.Rows[index];
            Guid sFileID = dr.Field<Guid>("FileID");
            LinkButton btnyes = new LinkButton();
            btnyes.Text="yes";
            //btnyes.Command+=new CommandEventHandler(gvFiles_RowCommand);

            LinkButton btnno = new LinkButton();
            btnno.Text="no";
            //btnno.Command+=new CommandEventHandler(gvFiles_RowCommand);


            if (e.CommandName == "remove")
            {
                gvFiles.Rows[index].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
                gvFiles.Rows[index].BorderColor = Color.FromName("Red");
                gvFiles.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text = "Are you sure?";
                gvFiles.Rows[index].Cells[2].Text = "yes";
                gvFiles.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text = "no";
                gvFiles.Rows[index].Cells[2].Controls.Add(btnyes);
                gvFiles.Rows[index].Cells[0].Controls.Add(btnno);
            }
            if (e.CommandName == "yes")
            {
                SQLCon.SQLCommand("DELETE TBL_Files WHERE FileID='" + sFileID + "' ");
                Response.Redirect("~/EditItem.aspx?CatID="+sCid+"&devID="+sdev);
            }
            if (e.CommandName == "no")
            {
                gvFiles.Rows[index].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;

            }
        }
```

I know I'm missing something essential but don´t know what to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you say you cannot get it to work, what happens? what does your delete link button HTML code look like? what does your gridview look like in the ASPX?

Comment: i cant get the yes/no buttons to work. delete works fine.

Comment: post your relevant ASPX code

Comment: just needed a moment

Comment: correct. this will NOT function because you are dynamically adding controls and on the next request, those just do not render or keep state (web is stateless). you have to ask yourself what you are wanting to do and why. perhaps you can add them but make them invisible and then make them visible when you need to.

Comment: well then you see the same thing why it wont work. I tried top make them visible and so on. i tried also to createt them in pageinit and pageload. but your comment doesnt help me at all.

Comment: I have explained why it doesn't work. for me, it works with my suggestion. you need to learn more about ASP.NET and how the web works. saying "it doesn't work" does not help. I have explained WHY it doesn't work with the approach you are taking.